# Compare a two column with the same table to remove duplicate

Tags: sql, informatica

A sample table with two column and I need to compare the column 1 and column 2 to the same table records and need to remove the column 1 + column 2 = column 2+column 1.

I tried to do self join and case condition. But its not working

Comment: what query did you try ?

Comment: What is your RDBMS? (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle...)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you can run a simple `select` like this if you have all reversed pairs in the table:

```
select col1, col2
from t
where col1 < col2;
```

If you have some singletons, then:

```
select col1, col2
from t
where col1 < col2 or
      (col1 > col2 and
       not exists (select 1
                   from t t2
                   where t2.col1 = t.col2 and
                         t2.col2 = t.col1
                  )
      );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **[except](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** operator.

> "*EXCEPT returns distinct rows from the left input query that aren't output by the right input query.*"

```
SELECT C1, C2 FROM table
Except
SELECT C2, C1 FROM table
```

Example with your given data set : **[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=403b5d81c4c9d2366ba43f1f1fca0b24)**

Answer (score 0):

I am posting the answer based on oracle database and also the columns are string/varchar:

delete from table where rowid in (
select rowid from table
where column1 || column2 =column2 || column1 )

Feel free to provide more input and we can tweak the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Okay. There might be a simpler way of doing this but this might work as well. {table} is to be replaced with your table name.

```
;with orderedtable as (select t1.col1, t1.col2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t1.col1, t1.col2 ASC) AS rownum
from (select distinct t2.col1, t2.col2 from {table} t2) as t1)

select f1.col1, f1.col2
from orderedtable f1
left join orderedtable f2 on f1.col1 = f2.col2 and f1.col2 = f2.col1 and f1.rownum < f2.rownum
where f2.rownum is null
```

Comment: Do let me know if it is not working or throwing an error. or you are expecting a different output

Answer (score -2):

The SQL below will get the reversed col1 and col2 rows:

```
select
    distinct t2.col1,t1.col2
from
    table t1
join
    table t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col2 and t1.col2 = t2.col1
```

And when we get these reversed rows, we can except them with the `left join` clause, the complete SQL is:

```
select
    t.col1,t.col2
from
    table t
left join
    (
      select
        distinct t2.col1,t1.col2
      from
        table t1
      join
        table t2 on t1.col1 = t2.col2 and t1.col2 = t2.col1
    ) tmp on t.col1 = tmp.col1 and t.col2 = tmp.col2
where
    tmp.col1 is null
```

Is it clear?

Comment: I think I have solved the problem, but why got negtive points?